# Azure and .json mimeType without web.config

Tags: azure, web-config

Adding to my web.config

```
<system.webServer>
  <staticContent>
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
  </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```

Allows my application to run on Azure, but will crash my remote IIS server because its already included.  Removing the remote IIS mimeType is not practical in this particular case.  I end up using a different web.config

Is there another mechanism by which I can configure Azure IIS mimeType so I don't have this problematic web.config?

I would like a single deployment package that will work on Azure and non Azure.

Comment: two thoughts: web.config transformation, but that means different deployment profiles or a startup task in Azure that makes the necessary tweaks to web.config.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This should work:

```
<system.webServer>
  <staticContent>
    <remove fileExtension=".json" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
  </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```

See also here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chaun/archive/2009/12/04/iis7-error-cannot-add-duplicate-collection-entry-of-type-mimemap-with-unique-key-attribute-fileextension.aspx

This doesn't make any difference to your overall IIS configuration, it just conditionally removes the mimeMap from the configuration of this particular site (as governed by this `web.config`) before adding it again.

Answer (score 3):

You can [create a startup task](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/avkashchauhan/archive/2011/05/28/how-to-perform-custom-iis-configuration-such-as-adding-dynamic-compression-for-additional-mime-types-in-web-role-using-startup-task.aspx) that adds the mime type on IIS level. This way you won't need to include it in your web.config:

```
"%windir%\System32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe" set config /section:staticContent /+"[fileExtension='.json',mimeType='application/json']"
exit /b 0
```